# How to iterate through a folder of images and print images inline in Jupyter notebook with Python 3.6

Tags: python, image, loops, jupyter-notebook

My following code iterates through a list of files & prints each image "inline" in a Jupyter Notebook with the filename.

```
from IPython.display import Image, display
listOfImageNames = ["0/IMG_1118.JPG","0/IMG_1179.JPG"]
for imageName in listOfImageNames:
    display(Image(filename=imageName))
    print(imageName)
```

However, I want to achieve the same output, but iterate through a *folder* of images, without having to reference each image file in the code. I have been battling with this one- can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using glob to search for JPG files!

```
import glob
from IPython.display import Image, display
for imageName in glob.glob('yourpath/*.jpg'): #assuming JPG
    display(Image(filename=imageName))
    print(imageName)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your images are present in different folders and on different levels, you should approach recursively:

```
from IPython.display import Image, display
from glob import glob
listofImageNames = glob('**/*.JPG', recursive=True)
for imageName in listOfImageNames:
    display(Image(filename=imageName))
    print(imageName)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Display 'n' number of images from a folder

If anyone wants to show n number of images from a folder, he can use the below code.
Remember to use `*` in `file_type` like `file_type = "*.jpg"`.
Because here glob will return a list of images.

```py
# Display n images from a folder

import glob
from IPython.display import Image, display

file_type = "*.jpg" # Assuming all jpg images of folder (Not a single)
src_path = "your_path/"
no_of_image_to_show = 5

def display_n_images(src_path, file_type, no_of_image_to_show):
    image_folder = glob.glob(src_path + file_type) # glob will return list of jpg images
    image_folder = image_folder[0:no_of_image_to_show] # splitting list

    for a_image in image_folder:
        display(Image(filename=a_image))
        print(a_image)
        
display_n_images(src_path, file_type, no_of_image_to_show)
```